# How does one declare that a particular variable is an array?

Tags: expect

I am looing for information on google about declaring array in expect but unable to find it.even the witki [link](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1032) for the line is empty.
I know i can set array values like `set arr("hh") "hhh"` but how do i declare it.

and can i print the whole array using one command or do i have to loop through it to print all the elements.

Or there is no such thing as declaring array in expect/tcl.i mean can we access any array
just by using `global` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to declare an array, but if you want to:

```
array set variableName {}
```

The last word is an empty list. If you have some default values you want to store in the array, you can say:

```
array set varname {key1 val1 key2 val2 ... ...}
```

If you're curious, here's how `parray` is implemented:

```
proc parray {a {pattern *}} {
    upvar 1 $a array
    if {![array exists array]} {
        error "\"$a\" isn't an array"
    }
    set maxl 0
    set names [lsort [array names array $pattern]]
    foreach name $names {
        if {[string length $name] > $maxl} {
            set maxl [string length $name]
        }
    }
    set maxl [expr {$maxl + [string length $a] + 2}]
    foreach name $names {
        set nameString [format %s(%s) $a $name]
        puts stdout [format "%-*s = %s" $maxl $nameString $array($name)]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't declare arrays in Expect (or Tcl in general) you just use them.
But arrays and other variables do have scope.  If you are in a proc and want to
refer to an array arr which has global scope you can either say `global arr` before
using it or prefix the name with :: each time you use it, eg. `set ::arr(hh) "hhh"; puts $::arr(hh)`.

There is a command parray to print a whole array, but this is loaded from library scripts rather than being built-in, so may not be available depending on how your Expect installation has been done. Eg.

```
expect1.1> set arr(a) ACBD
ACBD
expect1.2> set arr(b) "BBB bbb"
BBB bbb
expect1.3> parray arr
arr(a) = ACBD
arr(b) = BBB bbb
```